# How to prevent UITableViewCell from duplicating and reusing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm doing an exercise in which I use a tableview whose each row consists of 4 buttons.
What I want to do is to click on the button in each row to change its state(from normal to highlighted).
The question is , the cell automatically duplicates my tapping so that some buttons I didn't tap on become highlighted.
In addition, every time I scroll down the table view and go back to the previous position, the highlighted button position would be changed automatically.

I guess it must have something to do with the dequeReusableCell mechanism that I use in my code.
How to prevent this from happening? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Code for constructing a cell:

```
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
              let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChoiceCell
           cell.selectionStyle = .None
        return cell
```

Comment: I believe your problem lies in how you are constructing the cell `object` not in the reusability of it. Please add the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and how you are handling the button action.

Comment: The code is added. Thanks. I'm using the `deque` method

Answer (score 5):

You absolutely do not want to prevent the cell dequeuing process from doing what it does.  This isn't the right approach.

Instead, your data model needs to keep track of things that would effect the cell's state (such as whether a button is highlighted).  When something would happen to change the cell's state, in addition to changing the cell's state, also update your data model.

Now, when that cell scrolls off, it can be reused to represent something else in the data model.  Then when we scroll and we're ready to represent that original data object again, we use our data model to set the cell to the correct state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, for instance, when I tap on the first button in the first row, the first button in the seventh row becomes black as well (since it's the first cell that is not presenting in view). And when tapped on second row, the correspondent button in the eighth cell becomes highlighted too, and etc. How to fix this problem? Many thanks.